# Get a few lines of HDFS data

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am having a `2 GB` data in my `HDFS`.

Is it possible to get that data randomly.
Like we do in the Unix command line

```
cat iris2.csv |head -n 50
```

Comment: -n 2 does not give random data... it returns first 2 lines.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Native **head**

```
hadoop fs -cat /your/file | head
```

is efficient here, as cat will close the stream as soon as **head** will finish reading all the lines.

To get the **tail** there is a special effective command in hadoop:

```
hadoop fs -tail /your/file
```

Unfortunately it returns last kilobyte of the data, not a given number of lines.

Comment: how would you save the content of the | head into a hdfs file? thank you

Comment: I was trying something like this:  hdfs dfs -cat file.txt | head -9 | hdfs dfs -put - /dir/to/file2.txt, but yet it is not working. How would you do this?

Answer (score 10):

You can use head command in Hadoop too! Syntax would be

```
hdfs dfs -cat <hdfs_filename> | head -n 3
```

This will print only three lines from the file.

Answer (score 6):

The `head` and `tail` commands on Linux display the first 10 and last 10 lines respectively. But, the output of these two commands is not randomly sampled, they are in the same order as in the file itself.

The Linux shuffle - `shuf` command helps us generate random permutations of input lines & using this in conjunction with the Hadoop commands would be helpful, like so:

`$ hadoop fs -cat <file_path_on_hdfs> | shuf -n <N>`

Therefore, in this case if `iris2.csv` is a file on HDFS and you wanted 50 lines randomly sampled from the dataset:

`$ hadoop fs -cat /file_path_on_hdfs/iris2.csv | shuf -n 50`

Note: The Linux `sort` command could also be used, but the `shuf` command is faster and randomly samples data better.

Comment: This is the correct answer because none of the other answers talks about shuffling.

Answer (score 1):

```
hdfs dfs -cat yourFile | shuf -n <number_of_line>
```

Will do the trick for you.Though its not available on mac os. You can get installed GNU coreutils.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to load that data into Hive table, then you can do something like this:

```
SELECT column1, column2 FROM (
    SELECT iris2.column1, iris2.column2, rand() AS r
    FROM iris2
    ORDER BY r
) t
LIMIT 50;
```

EDIT:
This is simpler version of that query:

```
SELECT iris2.column1, iris2.column2
FROM iris2
ORDER BY rand()
LIMIT 50;
```

Answer (score 0):

Write this command

```
sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfs -cat "path of csv file" |head -n 50
```

50 is number of lines(this can be customize by the user based on the requirements)

Answer (score 0):

Working code:

```
hadoop fs -cat /tmp/a/b/20200630.xls | head -n 10

hadoop fs -cat /tmp/a/b/20200630.xls | tail -3
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using tail and cat for an avro file on HDFS cluster, but the result was not getting printed in correct encoding. I tried this and worked well for me.

```
hdfs dfs -text hdfs://<path_of_directory>/part-m-00000.avro | head -n 1
```

Change 1 to higher integer to print more samples from avro file.

Answer (score -1):

```
hadoop fs -cat  /user/hive/warehouse/vamshi_customers/* |tail
```

I think the head part is working as per the answer posted by @Viacheslav Rodionov works fine but for the tail part the one that I posted is working good.

Comment: This will download the entire file to your local machine, then tail it. Use `hdfs dfs -tail`