# Getting a sample of the pydoop HDFS file

Tags: python-2.7, hadoop, hdfs

I have a file stored in HDFS. I'm working with it as following:

```
from pydoop import hdfs

with hdfs.open(some_file, 'r') as t:
    run_func(t)
```

But I don't need to open and read all the file. A small sample of it will be enough.
I need to write a function, which allows me to work with sample as well as real file. For example:

```
with get_sample(hdfs.open(some_file, 'r'), percent) as s:
    run_func(s)
```

I know the simple and ugly solution. It can be realized as following:

1. We read source file from HDFS.
2. We randomly read n strings from file and write it to the new
   (destination) file.
3. Put the destination file into HDFS and open it.

But this solution may take much time because the source file can be large. Also it gives a temporary HDFS-file with the sample.

Is the much simple way to do this exists?

Comment: Do you have to use python?

Comment: @cricket_007, yes, I have. But if it's impossible to do this in Python, I'll glad to read about solution on other language (then I'll call this solution as a script using `subprocess`).

Comment: Well, just think about what `hdfs.open` is actually doing. It contacts the NameNode, gathers all block locations for files, then you read from all the DataNodes in a sequential ordering of the filesplits. Therefore, randomly sampling a file isn't really something HDFS is designed for. You are welcome to simply `head` or `tail` `n` lines from a file to get a sample.

Comment: The Linux shuffle command - `shuf` provides a simple way to achieve this. You could try this out - http://stackoverflow.com/a/42481973/3001733